# Is there a way to get larger buttons on the menu bar in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

It seems the hip new design for browsers since Google released Chrome is to minimize the browser's chrome in any way possible, usually including making the buttons tiny as possible.

The size of the Home, Refresh and Stop buttons in IE9 is maddening. It's nice that they are small and out of the way, but they present such a small target that they are not very easy to click on quickly.

There is an option for the other toolbars in IE9 to use larger icons, but I can't seem to find one for the MenuBar to increase the size of the refresh, stop and home buttons.

**Is there a registry hack or some other way to increase the size of the Menu Bar Buttons in IE8/IE9? Or maybe a way to revert it to the IE7 look, which was the last non-sucky version of the UI?**

Answer (score 1):

Via: http://my.opera.com/wikipedian/blog/ie9-small-icon

Paste the following into a .reg file and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\CommandBar]
"SmallIcons"=dword:00000000
```

Voila, bigger icons.